# Seeking help determining the limit of a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

I'm grappling with a problem involving a convergent sequence $\left\{{x}_{n}\right\}$ that satisfies the equation ${{x}_{n}}^3- \left(n^2 + 3n\right){x}_{n} - 3n^2 = 0$ for all $n \in {\mathbb{N}} .$ I'm tasked with finding the limit as n approaches infinity of ${x}_{n}$.
I've been exploring the properties of convergent sequences and attempted to manipulate the equation to discern the limiting behavior of ${x}_{n}$, but I'm encountering difficulties determining the exact approach to evaluate this limit.

Could someone provide guidance or a method to determine the limit of ${x}_{n}$ as $n$ tends to infinity, considering the given equation?

Comment: Note that $x_n=-n$ solves this.  As this isn't the solution you want, you can divide by it to get a quadratic.

Answer (score 4):

The expression $ x _ n ^ 3 - ( n ^ 2 + 3 n ) x _ n - 3 n ^ 2 $ is written as a polynomial in $ x _ n $, but since $ n $ (not $ x _ n $) is diverging to infinity, let's rewrite it as a polynomial in $ n $: $ ( - x _ n - 3 ) n ^ 2 + 3 x _ n n + x _ n ^ 3 $.  You may already see where this is going, but to really make it rigorous, you can divide by both sides of the equation by $ n ^ 2 $:  $$ - x _ n - 3 + \frac { 3 x _ n } n + \frac { x _ n ^ 3 } { n ^ 2 } = 0 \text . $$  Now take the limit of both sides as $ n \to \infty $, and (using the assumption that $ \lim _ n x _ n $ is finite) you'll get a simple equation for the limit that you can solve.